# How to install magit on windows

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I'm trying to install magit 1.2.0 into a fresh installation of emacs-24.2-bin-i386 downloaded from ftp.gnu.org, and 'make' step fails with the following error:

Opening output file: permission denied, d:/devel/emacs/release/emacs24/emacs-24.2/lisp/50magit.el

Where is it picking up the (non-existent) d:/devel/emacs... path from?  I assume it has something to do with the environment that emacs itself was built in, but I can't figure out how to override it.

Comment: I ended up hacking the Makefile

Comment: Here's what I did...I didn't address the 'd:/devel' question directly, just hacked it to make it work for me: https://gist.github.com/wytten/5137210

Answer (score 3):

Install Magit from [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/), using package.el.